# Не работает корректно insertBefore

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

Пишу код, чтобы при клике на определенную стрелку блок div перемещался в списке в зависимости от того какая стрелка нажата: стрелка вверх - div вверх, стрелка вниз - div вниз.

Код написал, но, стрелка вниз работает корректно, стрелка вверх почти корректно, в массиве позиция меняется, но insertBefore не меняет ее в html

Код стрелки вниз:

```js
let parent = document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task')[0].parentNode;
    let currentTask = this.parentElement;

    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task').length > 1)
        {
            if (currentTask.innerText == document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task p')[i].textContent)
            {
                if (i < document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task').length - 1)
                {
                    parent.insertBefore(document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task')[i + 1], currentTask);

                    let currentTaskInList = taskList[i];
                    let currentTaskStatusInList = taskListStatus[i];

                    taskList[i] = taskList[i + 1];
                    taskList[i + 1] = currentTaskInList;

                    taskListStatus[i] = taskListStatus[i + 1];
                    taskListStatus[i + 1] = currentTaskStatusInList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Код стрелки вверх:

```js
let parent = document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task')[0].parentNode;
    let currentTask = this.parentElement;

    for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task').length; i++)
    {
        if (document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task').length > 1)
        {
            if (currentTask.innerText == document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task p')[i].textContent)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    parent.insertBefore(document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task')[i - 1], currentTask);
                    
                    let currentTaskInList = taskList[i];
                    let currentTaskStatusInList = taskListStatus[i];

                    taskList[i] = taskList[i - 1];
                    taskList[i - 1] = currentTaskInList;

                    taskListStatus[i] = taskListStatus[i - 1];
                    taskListStatus[i - 1] = currentTaskStatusInList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Сделал вам простой вариант перемещения тудушки в списке

```js
function movingTodo(direction) {
  const todoActive = document.querySelector('.todo.active');

  switch (direction) {
    case 'top':
      let todoPrevEl = todoActive.previousElementSibling;
      if (!todoPrevEl) return;
      todoPrevEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', todoActive.outerHTML);
      break;
    case 'bottom':
      let todoNextEl = todoActive.nextElementSibling;
      if (!todoNextEl) return;
      todoNextEl.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', todoActive.outerHTML);
      break;
  }

  todoActive.remove();
}

const arrowTop = document.querySelector('.arrow.top');
const arrowBottom = document.querySelector('.arrow.bottom');

arrowTop.onclick = () => movingTodo('top');
arrowBottom.onclick = () => movingTodo('bottom');
```

```css
.todo-list {
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.todo-list .todo {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.todo-list .todo.active {
  background: #cff1ff;
}

.arrows {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.arrows .arrow {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #f1e4ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrows .arrow:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

.arrows .arrow:active {
  background: #dfc2ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows">
  <div class="arrow top">Top</div>
  <div class="arrow bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>

<div class="todo-list">
  <div class="todo">Todo 1</div>
  <div class="todo active">Todo 2</div>
  <div class="todo">Todo 3</div>
  <div class="todo">Todo 4</div>
  <div class="todo">Todo 5</div>
  <div class="todo">Todo 6</div>
  <div class="todo">Todo 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет смысла менять элементы местами. Всё делается гораздо проще.

```js
// Список элементов для краткости разделен "|"
`BTC|LTC|DASH|Solana|LUNA|LINK|ETH|BNB|USDT`.split`|`.map((item, idx) =>{
  // Создаем новый элемент
  const li = document.createElement('LI');
  // Прописываем ему стиль order в соответствии с порядком
  li.style.order = idx + 1;
  li.style.backgroundColor=`hsl(${40*idx},100%,80%)`;
  // Добавляем элемент в список
  ul.appendChild(li);
  // Вписываем код надписи и кнопок
  li.innerHTML = `<label contenteditable="true">${item}</label>
                  <button class="up"/><button class="down"/>`;
});

// Устанавливаем обработчик клика по кнопкам
ul.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn=>btn.onclick = click);

function click(e) {
  // Кнопка по которой кликнули
  const button = e.target;
  // Элемент в котором находится кнопка
  const item = button.closest("li");
  // Следующий номер элемента зависит от того какой класс у кноки
  // следующий номер либо +1 либо -1
  const nextOrder =
    +item.style.order + (button.classList.contains("down") ? 1 : -1);
  // Сам следующий элемент
  const next = ul.querySelector(`li[style^="order: ${nextOrder};"]`);
  // Если этот элемент найден, то
  if (next && next.tagName == "LI") {
    // Меняем местами стиль order
    [item.style.order, next.style.order] = 
    [next.style.order, item.style.order,];
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.add').forEach(btn=>
  btn.onclick = (e) => {
  // Создаем новый элемент
  const li = document.createElement('LI');
  // Порядки элементов
  const orders = [...ul.querySelectorAll('li')]
    .map(li=>+li.style.order);
    
  // Прописываем ему стиль order в соответствии с порядком    
  li.style.order =   
    /before|insert/.test(e.target.className) ?  
      Math.min(...orders) - 1 : 
      Math.max(...orders) + 1 ; 
   
  // Вписываем код надписи и кнопок
  li.innerHTML = `<label contenteditable="true"></label>
                  <button class="up"/><button class="down"/>`;

// Устанавливаем обработчик клика по кнопкам
  li.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn=>btn.onclick = click);
  
  // Добавляем элемент в список
  if(e.target.classList.contains('before')){
    ul.querySelector('li:first-child').before(li);
  }
  else if(e.target.classList.contains('insert')){
    ul.insertBefore(li,ul.querySelector('li'));
  }
  else if(e.target.classList.contains('append')){
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }else if(e.target.classList.contains('after')){
    ul.querySelector('li:last-child').after(li);
  }
 }
 );
```

```css
body { margin:0; }
ul {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}
li {
  height: 1.2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
label {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
button.before,
button.insert,
button.after,
button.append{ margin-left: 5%;}
button.add::before { content: "╋"; }
button.up::before { content: "▲"; }
button.down::before { content: "▼"; }
```

```html
<button class="add before">Добавить c before()</button>
<button class="add insert">Добавить c insertBefore()</button>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
<button class="add after">Добавить c after()</button>
<button class="add append">Добавить c appendChild()</button>
```

Comment: почему нет смысла? Мне это необходимо, чтобы пользователь мог поменять местами элементы. У меня пользователь создает сам все таски и должен иметь возможность менять их местами. А вы мне нечто не понятное предлагаете

Comment: я предлагаю сортировать элементы стилем `order`

Comment: ну а мне нужно, чтобы когда надо пользователь мог спустить или поднять задачу в списке задач на нужную позицию, например задача была последней в списке, а пользователь поднял ее на второе место

Comment: Ну смотрите, я подписал каждую строчку. Если вы пройдётесь пошаговой отладкой браузера по коду, увидите как все просто работает

Comment: не, спасибо, что попытались помочь, это мне не подходит. Даже, если попытаться это реализовать в проекте, мне практически весь проект прийдется переписывать

Comment: Что именно переделывать? Да разницы особо никакой по сути. Я просто не понимаю, что именно не получается? Как бы менять порядок стилями - это фича начала-середины 2010-х. Не новая, но и по старому тоже работает. Правда сложнее и не нагляднее.

Comment: Даже если менять порядок. Используйте лучше [before()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before) и [after()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) вместо insertBefore(), они удобнее.

Comment: Я создаю DOM элементы в js, то есть создаю div и в него элементы и так буквально каждый клик по кнопке, чтобы мне реализовать ваш способ мне необходимо переписывать большую часть проекта. Разница большая, либо я просто буду через insertBefore менять, либо через ваши стили, лишь больше заморачиваться. Ну а before и after в такой ситуации, что сделают? Предлагайте. Удобнее insertBefore? Мне он вполне удобен, только вот проблема возникла со стрелкой вверх, вот и задал вопрос, чтобы помогли решить почему не работает, потому что на стрелке вниз аналогичный код и она работает корректно

Comment: before и after работают с элементами относительно друг друга без надобности обращения к родительскому элементу. Ну как бы сортировать ими 100% проще чем insertBefore(). Вы конечно можете избегать их использования. Но в том, что они работают наглядней усомниться невозможно. Хороший код - такой код, где не нужно ничего исправлять. Хороший код короток и точен. У меня в любом проекте создание элементов по коду происходит только в одном месте. всегда. Потому, я не вижу проблем что-либо где-либо поменять.

Comment: сколько не пробовал, что after, что before применять, ни разу ничего не выходило. Лично мне проще с insertBefore, вы лучше подскажите как мне эту проблему с insertBefore решить. Ведь опять же, стрелка вниз ведь работает корректно

Comment: Ну если честно, у меня ваш код не запускается вообще ни кнопки вверх, ни вниз. Прочитал и не могу понять, какую роль выполняет цикл? Зачем он там нужен? И еще непонятно, у вас элемент имеет уникальный id `todo-task`. Так задумано? А какие id у других элементов списка? Приведите в пример хотя бы часть верски.

Comment: Я бы смог найти ошибку и адаптировать ваш код хоть с `insertBefore()` хоть с `before()` хоть с `order`. Но пока я вообще не понимаю логики, возможно вам видна цель. Я просто пока понять не могу. Никогда ни в одном примере работы ToDoList не встречал подобной логики.

Comment: Смотрите, я немного доработал код. Теперь там поля стали редактируемыми и появились 4 кнопки. Две сверху списка и две снизу.

Comment: просто это лишь две функции, которые нужно соответственно привязывать к кнопкам. todo-task у меня имеют все таски в списке, получаю их либо при клике по кнопке определенного таска получаю его родительский див, либо document.queryAllSelector('#todo-task')[index]... Цикл же и так понятен, я перебираю все элементы todo-task, в поисках необходимого и проверяю последний он или первый...

Comment: вы не в одном ToDoList не встречали подобной логики, потому что я не смотрю как другие реализовывали, я реализую так как я представляю себе ToDoList

Comment: Так я все равно не понимаю зачем там цикл? зачем перебирать все элементы и почему они имеют одинаковый id? Это никак не сможет работать

Comment: Про [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target)  и про [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) не слышали раньше?

Comment: нет, не слышал. Но все же. Почему у меня не работает стрелка вверх) Ведь стрелка вниз работает, а стрелка вверх нет, код схож

Comment: Да вот странно, по всем обстоятельствам должны не работать обе стрелки.

Comment: что за глупости? Почему же обе кнопки не должны работать? Как раз обе должны работать, одна ведь работает, на второй аналогичный код

Comment: Если у вас все элементы имеют одинаковый id, то `document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task')` код будет находить только первый элемент. Соответственно, одна из кнопок будет работать если там всего два элемента, а будет больше элементов, то будут обе кнопки не работать.

Comment: А главное, как вы ищете нужный элемент. Достаточно в двух элементах разместить одинаковый текст, и ваш поиск сломается.

Comment: вы давайте бред не несите. Я тестировал при количестве более двух элементов. Если не знаете, то лучше молчите

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поменять ноды местами

`parent.insertBefore(currentTask, document.querySelectorAll('#todo-task')[i - 1])`

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).